# Mysql InnoDB and MyISAM in single database

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I have database, where I have InnoDB and MyISAM tables. (InnoDB for PK a FK and MyISAM for fulltext indexes). On localhost everything works like a charm, but on endora webhosting (I have premium account) I'm getting this error when I'm trying to search.

> [2015-07-07 18-59-36] PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'trwcaeprojectmanagement.searchProjects' doesn't exist in /home/users/lubossuk/caejab.8u.cz/web/vendor/nette/database/src/Database/ResultSet.php:68  @  http://caejab.8u.cz/www/search/search?w … mit=Search  @@  exception-2015-07-07-18-59-36-fc34eacf91f6a41f05fa4aaaba2bb24d.html

Have someone experienced this problem?

[image: Here is database structure]

yep my bad mistake. Realy it was just capital P. Im feel so stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an issue with "case sensitivity" in table names.

It looks like table names are case sensitive in your web hosting environment, but not case sensitive on your localhost.

---

Reference: [**9.2.2 Identifier Case Sensitivity** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

> To avoid problems caused by such differences, it is best to adopt a consistent convention, such as always creating and referring to databases and tables using lowercase names. This convention is recommended for maximum portability and ease of use.